# IBM Lotus java XPage rest service - does it require signing for each user?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

I have made a Java ExtLib XPage custom REST service (CustomServiceBean) database basing on this solution:  https://setza-projects.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/RS/pages/363593730/IBM+Domino

I modified it though to use NotesCalendar class to create, update and delete events & resource reservations (so everything in fact is processed by the calendar, I'm only using raw documents for reading $Rooms in names.nsf and $Reservations in the reservations database). Everything works fine so far, it uses current session to open the calendar. I have some concerns regarding the permissions though.

What I want (and need):

- Ability to create calendar events & reservations as SPECIFIC users, I don't want just one "main" user that will create everything. I want each IBM Lotus user to be able to login with their credentials and create or update their calendar events.

This database with XPage will be deployed on our client's servers, so I don't want to require some special configuring for each user in order to be able to access my REST service.
I set up a new local installation of Lotus Server and created a new application using my XPage database as template, and I couldn't access the API neither with admin account or other accounts:

> HTTP JVM: CLFAD0229E: Security exception occurred servicing request for: /db.nsf/services.xsp/api - HTTP Code: 403. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml

As soon as I added my admin account to Server configuration -> Security -> Sign or run unrestricted methods and operations, it started working again. Not only for the admin account, but also for other accounts that were just created with an internet password and weren't assigned any specific roles or permissions. I didn't even sign the database.

So my question is, is this enough in order to get it working on client's production server? It kind of makes no sense to me, but it worked on my local server so I'm not sure, I'm new to IBM Lotus and I'm just doing an integration REST service.

If not, how could I do it, so I wouldn't really need to put the end client (Lotus server owner) into the hassle of configuring each user, while still being able to access the API as any Lotus user (providing the username and password)? I can either log-in as each indepentend user, or perform some impersonation with a "main" privileged account (create entries in someone else's calendar as him), although I think there is no way to do it in Java, because .getCalendar is a method of the Session class, I tried using createSession(), but I wasn't able to.

Answer (score 1):

Every notes application needs to be signed by an administrator with an ID known to the customers environment. The Id which is used to sign the db must have the appropriate rights, through the security tab in the server document. If the app is not signed properly, the app won't run. Once the app is signed, it runs in the authorized users session with the users rights.

Comment: So that  means if I sign it with an appropriate user, other (regular) users will also be able to execute the app? Thats how it currently works for me, I'm just not sure if it will be the same on servers of our clients

Comment: The user id which has signed the application must be in the list in the server document "Security > Programmability  Restrictions > Sign agents or XPages to run on behalf of the invoker". This is to restrict who is allowed to run code on the servers (signature based). If the application is up and running, every user in the ACL can access / use the application.